# In NodeJS how to save JSON object as text with node-postgres module?

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Finally i move forward from postgresql 9.1 to postresql 9.3 that supports JSON data type. Then the same code function properly.

However i think that what i want to do in the first place can be done... if someone know how i still want to know.

---

*Enviroment*
*node v0.10.28*
*pg v3.3.0*
*postgresql 9.1*

I got this insert query

```
INSERT INTO sessions(sid, user_id, session_object) VALUES ('id1', 1, '{"id":"fX2HkXYLclB","data": testing"}') RETURNING session_id
```

When testing it from pgAdmin (or command line) it works fine, but when my app try to run it from `pg.client.query` it try to turn the object as a string saving "[object object]". Here is the node code:

```
var session = {"id":"fX2HkXYLclB","data": "testing"};
var sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions(sid, user_id, session_object) VALUES (\'id1\', ' +
          ' 1, \''+JSON.stringify(session)+'\' ) RETURNING session_id';
console.log(sql);
client.query(sql, function(err, info) {
  if(err) {
  return addSessionCB(err, null);
  }
  return addSessionCB(null, info.rows[0].session_id);
});
```

After runing the application and testing the query manually on pg_admin the table show this 2 results.

```
 session_id |     sid     | user_id |            session_object             | active 
------------+-------------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------
          1 | fX2HkXYLclB |       1 | [object Object]                       | t
          2 | fX2HkXYLclB |       1 | {"id":"fX2HkXYLclB","data": "testing"}| t
(2 filas)
```

So, the question is ¿what im doing wrong with the `pg.query`?

---

Adding the original code, the code before is simplified for readability.

```
function addSession(session, addSessionCB) {
  log.log('debug', '[PSQL]Add new session on DB. \nsession: '+ session.id +
    '\nuser:'+ session.data.user);
  function executeAddSessionQuery(user_id){
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions(sid, user_id, session_object) VALUES (\'' +
      session.id + '\', '+user_id+', \''+JSON.stringify(session)+'\' ) ' +
      'RETURNING session_id';
    log.log('debug', '[PSQL]Adding session: '+session.id+' for user_id: '+
      user_id+'\nSQL: '+sql);
    client.query(sql, function(err, info) {
      if(err) {
        log.log('debug', '[PSQL]Error adding new session. \n'+err);
        return addSessionCB(err, null);
      }
      return addSessionCB(null, info.rows[0].session_id);
    });
  };
//to save session we need to know user id
  getUserByName({name: session.data.user},
    function getUserByNameCB(err, user_result){

      if(err || !user_result){
        //if error or not result we try to save new user
        log.log('debug', '[PSQL]Associated user not found. Creating a new ' +
          'user entry. ');
        addUser({name: session.data.user},
          function addUserCB(err, newUserID){
            if(err){
              log.log('warn', '[PSQL]Session user didn\'t exists and cannot be ' +
                'added to DB');
              return addSessionCB(err, null);
            }
            executeAddSessionQuery(newUserID);
        });
      } else {
        //if the user exist we use his id.
        executeAddSessionQuery(user_result.user_id);
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: That sounds like an `obj.toString()` problem. You're not using `toString()` anywhere on an object are you? I don't see it here, but otherwise your code should work.

Comment: Nope. The code is simplified here but very similar to to original version. `JSON.stringify(session)`give me a string so i dont need `session.toString()` fot nothing.

Comment: Can you share original code?

Comment: You got it, hopes it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The node postgres module has another form of **query**; where the 2nd parameter is an array of objects.  So in your case

```
var sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions(sid,user_id,session_object) VALUES ($1,$2,$3) RETURNING session_id';
var values = [id1,1,JSON.stringify(session)];
```

and then follow that up with

```
client.query(sql,values,function(err,info) {
...
```

This also has the added benefit of guarding against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yeah... i have try that too, but still got the same result.